# Changing degrees to metres

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, latitude-longitude, units

I got a shapefile which is in degrees format. For a vector analysis, I need it to be in meters to set a maximum distance. I can't do that with degrees.

I know about on the fly CRS change; That's not what I ask about.

Comment: Save the data using a fitting m-based CRS. Preferrably not EPSG3857.

Comment: so I changed the CRS of the layer to EPSG 4326 wich uses meters; exported the layer and added it to the Projekt it´s still in degrees

Comment: a) don't ever change the CRS, always save to/reproject. b) EPSG4326 is the global degree based CRS.

Comment: Yeah that Worked Thank You very much ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Save/reproject the data using a fitting m-based CRS.